# How to use JsForce in a Salesforce Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, jsforce

**BACKGROUND**

I would like to be able to interact with the various Salesforce REST API from client-side JavaScript code, without needing to go via a Apex controller method and then making a separate Apex callout.

I have created a POC component:

**Component**

```
<aura:component controller="JavaScriptForceController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.jsforce + '/jsforce.min.js'}" />
</aura:component>
```

**JavaScript Controller**

```
({
    doInit : function(cmp, event, helper) {

        helper.callAction(cmp, 'c.getSessionID', null, function(sessionId){
            console.log(sessionId) 

            let params = {};
            params.sessionId = sessionId;
            params.serverUrl = 'https://xxx-dev-ed.lightning.force.com';
            params.instanceUrl = 'https://xxx-dev-ed.lightning.force.com';
            params.logLevel = 'DEBUG';
            params.version = '43.0';

            var conn = new jsforce.Connection(params);
            conn.sobject("Account").describe(function(err, meta) {

                if (err) return console.error(err); 

                console.log('Label : ' + meta.label);
                console.log('Num of Fields : ' + meta.fields.length);

                meta.fields.forEach(function(field) {
                    console.log(field.name + ' - '  + field.label + ' - ' + field.type);
                });
            });
        });
    }
})
```

**Apex Controller**

```
public class JavaScriptForceController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getSessionID(){

        return UserInfo.getSessionID();

    }
}
```

**And a JavaScript Helper**

```
({
    callAction : function(cmp, methodName, params, callback){
        var self = this;
        var action = cmp.get(methodName); 
        if (params != null) action.setParams(params);
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            console.log(methodName + ' ' + state);
            if(cmp.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS"){
                var result = response.getReturnValue();
                console.log(result);
                if (callback) callback(result);
            } else if (state === "ERROR"){
                console.log(response.getError());
            }
        });

        $A.getCallback(function() {
            $A.enqueueAction(action); 
        })();  
    },
})
```

**CSP Trusted Sites Definition**

Add a rule: `https://xxx-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com`

**Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS).**

Add rules:

1. `https://xxx-dev-ed.lightning.force.com`
2. `https://xxx-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com`

**QUESTIONS**

1. Why do I still get these errors (see below)?
2. Is it even possible to even use JsForce in Lightning?
3. If not, are there any other JavaScript librarys I could use to easily interact with the Salesforce REST APIs?

> method=GET,
>   url=/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Account/describe GET
>   https://xxx-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Account/describe
>   401 (Unauthorized)
>
> JsForce_Test:1 Failed to load
>   https://xxx-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Account/describe:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://xxx-dev-ed.lightning.force.com' is
>   therefore not allowed access.
>
> The response had HTTP status code 401.
>
> jsforce.min.js:3 elappsed time : 168msec jsforce.min.js:3 
>   status=400,  url=/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Account/describe
>
> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response
>   https://xxx-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Account/describe
>   with MIME type application/json.
>
> JavaScriptForce.js:24 Error: Access Declined

**Reference**

- [JsForce: Class: Connection](https://jsforce.github.io/jsforce/doc/Connection.html)
- [JsForce: Connection Examples](https://jsforce.github.io/document/)

Comment: Try using a container component to make the call... This could prevent the cross origin issues you are facing.

Comment: @CasparHarmer Thanks for responding. What do you mean by 'Container Component'?

Comment: Great question. I believe Caspar means a lightning:container in which a VF page could live doing the call outs and communicating stuff back to LEX cmps via window.message => https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/container_overview.htm

Comment: Also check the server/instance urls. You put 'lightning' in and I believe it should point to the classic URL like https://xxx-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com

Answer (score 8):

> Why do I still get these errors (see below)?

You've got two things working against you: CORB and Lightning Session Id. First, [CORB](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#corb) is a new security feature that prevents certain types of resources from being returned to the client. As far as I can tell, you can't circumvent this at all. Second, the Lightning Session Id does not have API access, so you'd have to hit the server at least once to get a compatible Session ID anyways. Overall, whatever you're attempting to do will not work well in Lightning. You should be able to do this in Visualforce, because it has an API-capable session Id *and* doesn't have to go across domains. The original error would have been INVALID_SESSION_ID (so you got a 401), but it was filtered out by CORB, so all your script sees is the secondary error.

> Is it even possible to even use JsForce in Lightning?

Absolutely not. CORB will block all responses, because there's no API endpoint mapped to lightning.force.com. This is a browser-based security feature.

> If not, are there any other JavaScript librarys I could use to easily interact with the Salesforce REST APIs?

Because of all the security restrictions, you simply won't be able to do this. There was a "hack" you could do in the past (grabbing a Visualforce Session Id), but it won't work any longer. You will necessarily need Visualforce if you want any sort of API access.

Comment: So, in conclusion, VF + lightning:container, right?

Comment: @ChristianSzandorKnapp I think so, as long as the VF page makes the calls; you'd basically be using the Visualforce page as a proxy server to Salesforce. I can't see how this would be the lesser of two evils as opposed to just using Apex Code directly.

Comment: I agree for most Usecases. Valid in my eyes would be tooling API for example.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thank you. Do we know if there is any plan by Salesforce to a Lightning JavaScript library which has the same capability, or is it impossible due to the security restrictions?

Comment: @sfdcfox Please may I clarify, even if I got the correct Session ID for JsForce, I still would not be able to use it because of CORB regardless of my CORS settings?

Comment: @Robs That's correct. Unless salesforce.com actively adds an API endpoint on the lightning.force.com URL (which they likely will never do), there's no means of calling any API other than Lightning-approved methods. Like others have said, the only client-side solution would be a Visualforce proxy, which practically means you may as well just write a VF page instead of a component.

Comment: I am slightly confused. Because I am able to call out to other external APIs by setting CORS. So I am not 100% sure why this won't work (being dumb sorry). Is this CORB restriction set on the Salesforce REST API servers?

Comment: @Robs CORBs is a new *browser* feature. It restricts cross-domain access to JSON, XML, and HTML resources (and, as a special feature, `text/plain` as well). You'll need to read the specs.

Comment: @Robs CORB + Lightning essentially means that all callouts to APIs will need to be Apex-based to succeed. I suspect CORB broke a lot of integrations and apps in Salesforce.